# Searching an ANSI special character in a file with PHP

Tags: php, string, file, search, ansi

I have the following [binary file](https://amoksys.com.br/info/test/reading_file/1.tmp), and i need to read it and find the character '®️'.

If i open the file in windows notepad, i can find the character.
If i open the hosted file, i can find the character

But when trying with PHP, i can not find the character.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = "";

while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
$r = "®️";

$strpos = strpos($contents, $r);
$mb_strpos = mb_strpos($contents, $r);

echo "<p>strpos function searching for '{$r}': " . ($strpos === false ? "Not found" : $strpos) . "</p>";
echo "<p>mb_strpos function searching for '{$r}': " . ($mb_strpos === false ? "Not found" : $mb_strpos) . "</p>";
                    
$found = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
    $byte = $contents[$i];
    if ($byte == $char) {
         echo "<p>reading character per character of 'contents', {$r} position is {$i}</p>";
         $found = true;
         break;
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the function stream_get_contents

```
$offset = 0;
while ($byte = stream_get_contents($handle, 1, $offset)) {
    if ($byte == "$r") {
        echo "<p>{$r} position is {$i}</p>";
        break;
    }

    $offset++;
}
```

And i also tried changing the encoding of the variable $r with the following functions

```
utf8_decode($r);
mb_convert_encoding($r, 'CP1252');
mb_convert_encoding($r, 'CP1252', 'UTF-8');
mb_convert_encoding($r, 'Windows-1252');
mb_convert_encoding($r, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8')
```

Does anybody knows how to properly find the character in the file?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to figure out (= as in: use a hexeditor) the real encoding of your file first? (Btw, "ANSI" isn't an encoding. Obligatory: [What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](https://kunststube.net/encoding/))

Comment: An encoding cannot be guessed or determined. You have to know the encoding of a file in order to be able to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test and this test code works fine(I haven't change the encoding):

```
$handle = fopen('test.txt','r');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize ('test.txt'));
var_dump($contents);
var_dump(strpos($contents,"®"));
fclose($handle);
```

and the text in the test.txt is:

```
laksjdflakjs®️alskjdf
```

And when I do this test, I've found something strange: your '®️' in your question contains a surplus space char, maybe that's the reason ur code didn't run well

Comment: I have created a new file with same text as in your way, and the character was found. While opening both files in notepad++, noticed in bottom right of the window, where the file 1.tmp says "ANSI", the new file says "UTF-8", so i tried using utf8_encode function and it worked, i could find the character. But, changing the file to UTF-8 makes the file useless for the purposes i want. I need to find a way to read the 1.tmp without changing it to UTF-8...